# Buscar un valor dentro de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo que verificar si dentro de un objeto se encuentra un valor y que al final la función retorne un true o un false. Todo esto con recursividad, solo que no logro hacer que funcione el for in, cuando empieza a recorrer el objeto se queda en la primera clave valor.

```
 function buscaMascota(obj, nombre) {
  for (let i in obj) {
    if (obj[i] === nombre) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
console.log(buscaMascota(mascota, "Piolin"));
```

Comment: eso no es recursividad, que necesitas... buscar en todas las propiedades del objeto y verificar si existe el valor 'Piolin'?

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías adjuntar tu objeto?... por cierto, prueba quitar el `else` y pon el `return false`  fuera del `for...in`.

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas el método values()? Object.values(nombreObjeto). https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta dando un objeto de ejemplo, ademas considera que tal vez te estas equivocando de termino con recursividad, solo necesitas revisar el listado de forma superficial al parecer, si es así acláralo, editando la pegunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez esto puede ayudarte solo cambie el return false al final porque eso lo frenaba, en tu rutina preguntaba si existía la propiedad y como no lo encontraba en la primera iteración enviaba false.

Ahora solo al terminar el recorrido envía false

```
 function contieneValor(objeto, valor) {
  // Recorre todas las propiedades del objeto
  for (let propiedad in objeto) {
    // Verifica si el valor de la propiedad es igual al valor que se está buscando
    if (objeto[propiedad] === valor) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  // Si no se encuentra el valor en ninguna propiedad del objeto, se devuelve false
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Hola Edwin, gracias por tu colaboración, te sugiero que edites tu respuesta y la adaptes a la consigna del OP, que claramente indica la necesidad de usar recursión, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, quería darte la mía que aplica recursividad al código para hallar la solución. Utiliza el método de Object [entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) y [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), que devuelve un objeto iterador que implementa los métodos next(), return() y throw():

```
let mascota = { // objeto
  tipo: 'Perro',
  raza: 'daschund',
  nombre: 'firulais',
  color: 'marron'
}

const mascota_entries = Object.entries(mascota) // entries devuelve un array de arrays con los pares clave/valor del objeto
const iterator = mascota_entries[Symbol.iterator](); // creamos un iterador con Symbol.iterator 

function search(iterator, tosearch){
  let result = iterator.next() // obtenemos los valores del primer resultado en la iteracion
  if(!result.done){ // mientras el iterador no haya terminado:
    if(result.value[1] == tosearch) return true // si el resultado de la iteracion es igual al valor buscado devolvemos true
    else return search(iterator, tosearch) // sino aplicamos la recursion, pasando el iterador que apuntara al siguiente elemento
  } else return false // si el iterador termino retorna false
}

console.log(search(iterator, 'firulais'))
```